# Stack with counting page

Tags: javascript, html, counter, default-value, counting

```
<div class="form__controls incrementor">
  <a href="#" data-target="#fieldpages" @click.prevent="updatePagesCount(-1)">
     <i class="ico-minus"></i>
   </a>

<input type="number" class="field incrementor__field" name="num_pages" id="fieldpages" v-model="pagesCount">

  <a href="#" data-target="#fieldpages" @click.prevent="updatePagesCount(+1)">
    <i class="ico-plus"></i>
   </a>
</div>
```

I stuck here, I am making an order form and need to start counting at 0. Just set default value to "0" or I don't know how to solve this

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean you want the input element to default to "0"? What happened when you tried a `value="0"` attribute? Or you could change the `updatePagesCount()` function to set it to "0" if it is currently blank, but you haven't shown the existing code for that function. Please [edit] your question to add that code and to explain more clearly what the desired behaviour is.

Comment: This isn't basic HTML - `@click.prevent` is not a typical HTML attribute. What are you using here?